# Camel Route Losing Message on restart in camel rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, rabbitmq-exchange

I am using camel-rabbitmq. 
Here is my route defination

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("rabbitmq:TEST?queue=TEST&concurrentConsumers=5")
            .routeId("jms")
            .autoStartup(false)
            .throttle(10)
            .asyncDelayed()
            .log("Consuming message ${body} to ${header.deliveryAddress}")
            .process(new Processor() {

                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println(atomicLong.decrementAndGet());
                }
            })

            ;
        }
    });
```

When I push 500 messages to this queue , when stop and start route all message on channel will be lost ,wonder where they are going.

If I configure same route with `&autoAck=false` it is working properly but losing performance. Why camel not offering same behavior with and without autoAck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed my problem doing following change in rabbitmqconsumer of camel-rabbitmq

```
    public void handleCancelOk(String consumerTag) {
        // no work to do
        log.info("Received cancelOk signal on the rabbitMQ channel");
        **downLatch.countDown();**
    }
```

```
  @Override
    protected void doStop() throws Exception {
        if (channel == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.requeueChannel=openChannel(consumer.getConnection());
         if (tag != null && isChannelOpen()) {
            channel.basicCancel(tag);
        }
        stopping=true;
         downLatch.await();         

        try {
            lock.acquire();
            if (isChannelOpen()) {
                channel.close();
            }
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            log.error("Timeout occured");
            throw e;
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            log.error("Thread Interrupted!");
        } finally {
            lock.release();
        }


    }
```

By doing this camel route will for message to consumed and avoided message loss.

Comment: You are just replicating the behaviour of autoack = false by rejecting the message via shutdown hook. But just curious, what performance gain did you observe?

Comment: Getting huge performance gain, also autoAck=false also cause duplicate message,consumer hang.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check rabbitmq consumer prefetch count 
[consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html)
I think By default consumer picks all the messages in queue to its memory buffers.
If you set the prefetch count to 1, consumer will acknowledge messages one by one.
All the other unacknowledged will be present in the queue in ready state. Waiting to be picked up, after the consumer completes it task on the previous message picked.

Comment: You can check apache camel rabbitmq doc to get how to use prefetch options in a camel rabbit route https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/rabbitmq-component.html

Comment: Prefetch count works with manual ACK. Manual ACK will drop performance. And problem was with auto ac on

Comment: yes manual ack would impact performance. When i first faced this situation, loosing messages on restart was not an option for me. So i used manual ack and increased the number of concurrent consumers.